# Change file format in open file dialog permanently into *.* in R?

Tags: r, file-format

I know about the setwd command in the Rprofile.site to change the working directory, but I want to change the file format permanently into * . * (default is *.R).
Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: You want to change the file format where? You mean in the standard R GUI file open dialog? Or are you using a different front end?

Comment: Yes, in the standard R GUI file open dialog, sorry.

Comment: R has a GUI?  Please add a tag to your question showing the operating system you're using.

Comment: Simplest way is to write a wrapper func.  **BUT** there is no "file format" in `setwd` . What are you actually doing?  Please post the code you're using.

Comment: Maybe, I wrote a bit confusing... I save all scripts as a .txt-file and I want to save time while opening my scripts. Thus, I'm looking for an option to set the possible file formats in the open file dialog as * . * as default instead of *.R.

Comment: Don't save as .txt and don't open scripts that way.

Comment: Why not just save your scripts as .R?

Comment: Ok, looks like this would be the easiest way. Thanks a lot!